# Need to datepicker control set default dateformat in client system dateformat

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

As i am create datepicker control in javascript.

this my code

```
 $("#dateformat").ejDatePicker({ 
    value: new Date() 
 });
```

doesn't set properties of locale and format in that control.
my system datetime format en-US.so i getting output `5/13/2015(mm/dd/yyyy)`

if i will change system country UK locale en-GB in that case my control does't render `13/5/2015(dd/mm/yyyy)`

Note : i have used globalization.js script file. in that script file default locale en-US so i could't get current system date format.
anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the date format with any valid combination of `d`, `D`, `m`, `M`, `y` and `Y`'s

```
$("#dateformat").ejDatePicker({ 
    value: new Date(),
    dateFormat: "dd-MMM-yy"
 });
```